# how to add new ntfs folder permission

Tags: delphi

how can i add new file/folder ntfs access permission in delphi ?

i am using this method to add new permission but this method removes all of permission on a folder then create only specified permission , i want to just add new one and save another permisions also this method remove folder owner how to save that information and add.

```
function SetNTFSPermission(foldername, username:string):boolean;    //B2415 MDE
var
 pDACL: PACL;
 pEA: PEXPLICIT_ACCESS_W;
 R: DWORD;
begin
 result := true;
 pEA := AllocMem(SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
 BuildExplicitAccessWithName(pEA, PChar(username), GENERIC_ALL{GENERIC_READ},Winapi.AccCtrl.GRANT_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT{NO_INHERITANCE});
 R := SetEntriesInAcl(1, pEA, nil, pDACL);
 if R = ERROR_SUCCESS then
 begin
  if SetNamedSecurityInfo(pchar(foldername), Winapi.AccCtrl.SE_FILE_OBJECT,DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, pDACL, nil) <> ERROR_SUCCESS then result := false;
  LocalFree(Cardinal(pDACL));
 end
 else result := false;
end;
```

thanks

Comment: You need to query the current permissions and then modify that list as needed.  You are instead building a new list and omitting the previous permissions from it.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau can you write a sample code ? i need it also :) and i am not good at c++ please thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the Microosoft documentation (C/C++, but Delphi is very similar):

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/modifying-the-acls-of-an-object-in-c--
>
> ```
> DWORD AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor (
>     LPTSTR pszObjName,          // name of object
>     SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,  // type of object
>     LPTSTR pszTrustee,          // trustee for new ACE
>     TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm,   // format of trustee structure
>     DWORD dwAccessRights,       // access mask for new ACE
>     ACCESS_MODE AccessMode,     // type of ACE
>     DWORD dwInheritance         // inheritance flags for new ACE
> ) 
> {
>     DWORD dwRes = 0;
>     PACL pOldDACL = NULL, pNewDACL = NULL;
>     PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
>     EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
>
>     if (NULL == pszObjName) 
>         return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
>
>     // Get a pointer to the existing DACL.
>
>     dwRes = GetNamedSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType, 
>           DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
>           NULL, NULL, &pOldDACL, NULL, &pSD);
>     if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {
>         printf( "GetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
>         goto Cleanup; 
>     }  
>
>     // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new ACE. 
>
>     ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
>     ea.grfAccessPermissions = dwAccessRights;
>     ea.grfAccessMode = AccessMode;
>     ea.grfInheritance= dwInheritance;
>     ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TrusteeForm;
>     ea.Trustee.ptstrName = pszTrustee;
>
>     // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE
>     // into the existing DACL.
>
>     dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, pOldDACL, &pNewDACL);
>     if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)  {
>         printf( "SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n", dwRes );
>         goto Cleanup; 
>     }  
>
>     // Attach the new ACL as the object's DACL.
>
>     dwRes = SetNamedSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType, 
>           DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
>           NULL, NULL, pNewDACL, NULL);
>     if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)  {
>         printf( "SetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
>         goto Cleanup; 
>     }  
>
>     Cleanup:
>
>         if(pSD != NULL) 
>             LocalFree((HLOCAL) pSD); 
>         if(pNewDACL != NULL) 
>             LocalFree((HLOCAL) pNewDACL); 
>
>         return dwRes;
> }
> ```

You're close, but you need to do a [GetNamedSecurityInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfoa) first.